# Does Full-Stack Web Development Violate DRY?

Tags: python, django, reactjs, database, rest

I'm planning on using Django with ReactJS to build a GUI for a complicated database. In order to have features such as auto-completing searching for particular fields, etc, I suppose that using JavaScript is necessary. Is there a way to reuse the models that I made in Python so I don't have to repeat a bunch of code in writing the Django serializers for a REST API and in the models in ReactJS?

Comment: Do you mean, you don't need to select auto-complete values from database for each request, because you are sure have a same result always?

Comment: @Tazoleladze No, because there are many interconnected tables  with many-to-many relationships (e.g. Person with a many-to-many relationship with itself called Friends), it's helpful to auto-complete as searching for one person, and then use the Friends table to find a particular Friend.

Comment: Its hard to understand what do you need. Please provide a example in problem description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking with others who know more than I, I am letting the React frontend be fairly minimal: it will know how to display the data sent to it via Django Channels json packets. The Django backend will handle all the rest (including much of the logic of knowing which pages are accessible from various parts of the database). Thus, the frontend will need minimal knowledge of the structure of the database, and that will preserve the DRY principle.

Answer (score 0):

So, as far as I understand, you should create an API, so that your front-end can communicate with your backend. If that is the case, then you do not have to use again any of your models, you will just send a response with the data that you want for each endpoint.

I hope that helps, please let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Yes, but I need my front-end to use some logic on the model before it is sent back to the backend, so the front-end needs knowledge of the model.